# Problem in building relationships query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose we have 3 tables , `User` , `Report` and `Job`. In users table we having 2 columns to use, `id` and `job_id`, in `report` table , we have `user_id` and `job_id`'.

So I need all users with report detail, whose `job_id` and `user_id` matched User table. I want to do it with relationship.

I made that query.

Problem is how to write multiple where clause with report, `(where user_id,job_id)`.

`User:: select(*)->with("report")->paginate(10);`

Comment: May I asked what is your relationship with the given tables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

User model define

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

Job model define

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
}
```

Then use

```
User::select(*)->with("job.reports")->paginate(10);
```

Comment: or User::select(*)->with("job.reports")-`>`paginate(10);

Comment: User:: select (*)->with(["report"=>function ($q){
$q->select(*);
}])-paginate(10);  i jst want where clause with user id in report, is it possible?

Comment: this one? `User::with(['report' => function($query) {
    return $query->where('')
}])`

Comment: Yup, but i want multiple were clause, get reports where job_id and user id exists in user table...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like

```
User::whereHas('report', function ($q) use ($id, $sample) {
    $q->where('id', $id)
      ->where('sample', $sample);
})->get();
```

`$id` are just sample variable you can pass on to closure, while `whereHas` able to check if there's existing relationship

or something like,

```
User::WhereHas('report', function ($q) use ($id, $sample) {
    $q
        ->where('id', $id) // this part here your using where on reports table
        ->where('sample', $sample);
})
->where('id', $user_id); // the part here your using where on users table
->get();
```

Comment: I m getting users .with relationship , i m  getting reports by id,user_id, ... but problem is user table have a column named job_id, n i jst want to use where condition in report relationship, where job_id n user_id matched with user.. n get that record in report.

Comment: you can add more relation to whereHas like `whereHas('jobs', 'report'`